# Separating templates from logic in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, templates, plugins

I'm wondering the best way to separate my plugin's templates from the actual logic. Currently I use a series of actions & filters to enable theme authors to alter controls ect from my plugin but it's not very intuitive.

I've heard of template engines like twig but not sure on how big the uptake is on these & whether it might confuse more than it helps.

Does anyone have any experience with this in WordPress?

Thanks

Comment: I think this is a better question to ask on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/. ;)

Comment: Yep. I know, although the WP stack exchange is too focused for this question. I'm interested in other peoples methods, but willing to delete if the majority think its in the wrong place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By my experience of plugin development, I have come up with a simple MVC like way separate plugin files. Basically what you can do is use the same folder structure that WordPress core uses. For example, if your plugin name is 'Related Posts' (rp), then the folder structure can be as follows:

- wp-content/plugins/root_plugin_folder/rp-admin : This should contain all files which are needed for admin interface of your plugin. Typically the view files for your options page etc.
- wp-content/plugins/root_plugin_folder/rp-content : This should contain all plugin's template files. This folder can also store stylesheets, js - basically all that is used within the theme
- wp-content/plugins/root_plugin_folder/rp-includes : This is the folder for all model files, includes your plugins core libraries, any other libraries used. Basically pure php code of model or view type.
- wp-content/plugins/root_plugin_folder/index.php : This file will be the bootstrap which will have plugin name, description markdown and plugin initiation filters and actions etc.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Great answer, wondering though how would theme authors go about altering the views?

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever used the [model-view-controller (MVC)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) method? Its a method of programming to separate logic from presentation.

Comment: Yep, love MVC & our architecture is kinda like that (although WP doesn't make MVC easy). How would you go about overriding views?

Comment: That I don't know hehe. XD I've never actually used MVC before my self hehe

Comment: Ah, now worries. You should its great! Thanks for the answer though :)